# How to merge cell in the data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I have below dataframe:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Jl1g.png)

And need to convert to below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PVxX.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If both columns are strings (if it's integers you have to first convert it to string using df["A"].astype(str) and df["B"].astype(str)), you can concatenate them directly:

`df["A"] = df["A"] + df["B"]`